# CFML converting evaluate() query string to structure syntax

Tags: coldfusion, structure, cfml

I have the code below inside of a loop so as the loop iterates I'm setting a dynamic variable `temp` to the value of the `getAdvisor_Advisors.advisor_ID` for the current loop iteration.

```
<cfset temp = "getAdvisor_Advisors#LoopCount#.advisor_ID">
```

This cfinvoke below calls a query that I pass in the dynamic "temp" variable but have to use the slow evaluate(temp) around it to get the proper value.

```
<cfinvoke component="com.appointments" method="get_All_Appointments" returnvariable="getAppointments">
      <cfinvokeargument name="Advisor_ID" value="#evaluate(temp)#">
      <cfinvokeargument name="StartDay" value="#dateFormat(form.cal,'dd')#">
      <cfinvokeargument name="StartMonth" value="#dateFormat(form.cal,'mm')#">
      <cfinvokeargument name="StartYear" value="#dateformat(form.cal,'yyyy')#">             
</cfinvoke>
```

I'm wanting to rewrite the `temp` variable and `evaluate()` to not use evaluate. I'm told I can use the structure syntax to reference it sort of like the following:

**Without evaluate:**

```
<cfset foo = qBar["text#lang#"][CurrentRow]>
getAdvisor_Advisor["advisor_ID"][CurrentRow]
```

How do I rewrite

```
<cfset temp = "getAdvisor_Advisors#LoopCount#.advisor_ID">
```

using structure syntax?

Adding more of the code so you can see why this is complicated these are compound loops.

```
            <cfquery name="getAdvisor_Advisors1" dbtype="query" cachedWithin="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,15,0)#">
                Select *
                From getAdvisors
                Where Express = 'FR/SO' 
                Order by Specialization, Advisor
            </cfquery>

            <cfquery name="getAdvisor_Advisors2" dbtype="query" cachedWithin="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,15,0)#">
                Select *
                From getAdvisors
                Where Express = 'JR/SR' 
                Order by Specialization, Advisor
            </cfquery>

            <cfquery name="getAdvisor_Advisors3" dbtype="query" cachedwithin="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,15,0)#">
                Select *
                From getAdvisors
                Where Specialization IS NULL AND Appointments = 1 AND Campus_ID > 0
                Order by Campus_ID, Advisor
            </cfquery>

            <cfquery name="getAdvisor_Advisors4" dbtype="query" cachedwithin="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,15,0)#">
                Select *
                From getAdvisors
                Where Specialization IS NOT NULL
                AND Title != 'BCC-GA' 
                Order by Specialization, Advisor
            </cfquery>

            <div id="calendarGrid">
                <!--- looping over the filter queries above that split advisors into groups --->   
                <cfloop index="LoopCount" from = "1" to = "4"> 
                    <!--- FR/SO Advisors --->
                    <cfif LoopCount LTE 3>
                        <cfset currGroup = "campus_id">
                    <cfelse>
                        <cfset currGroup = "specialization">
                   </cfif>
                    <cfoutput query="getAdvisor_Advisors#LoopCount#" group="#currGroup#">
                    <div class="advisorGrouping">
                        <div id="calcontainer">
                            <table class="pickme" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
                                <tr class="hdr">
                                    <td width="6.9%">
                                        <cfif (Specialization IS "BCC") OR (Specialization IS "HONORS")>
                                            #uCase(Specialization)#
                                        <cfelse>                           
                                            #uCase(Campus_Text)# 
                                        <cfif Len(Express) NEQ 0>
                                            - #uCase(Express)#
                                        </cfif>
                                    </cfif>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="4.9%" class="border">8:00</td>
                                    <td width="4.9%" class="border">8:30</td>
                                    <td width="4.9%" class="border">9:00</td>
                                    <td width="4.9%" class="border">9:30</td>
                                    <td width="4.9%" class="border">10:00</td>
                                    <td width="4.9%" class="border">10:30</td>
                                    <td width="4.9%" class="border">11:00</td>
                                    <td width="4.9%" class="border">11:30</td>
                                    <td width="4.9%" class="border">12:00</td>
                                    <td width="4.9%" class="border">12:30</td>
                                    <td width="4.9%" class="border">1:00</td>
                                    <td width="4.9%" class="border">1:30</td>
                                    <td width="4.9%" class="border">2:00</td>
                                    <td width="4.9%" class="border">2:30</td>
                                    <td width="4.9%" class="border">3:00</td>
                                    <td width="4.9%" class="border">3:30</td>
                                    <td width="4.9%" class="border">4:00</td>
                                    <td width="4.9%" class="border">4:30</td>
                                    <td width="4.9%" class="border">5:00</td>
                                </tr>
                                <cfoutput group="advisor_id">


                                    <cfset temp = "getAdvisor_Advisors#LoopCount#.advisor_ID">


                                    <!--- get Appts for cal date --->   
                                    <cfinvoke component="com.appointments" method="get_All_Appointments" returnvariable="getAppointments">
                                        <cfinvokeargument name="Advisor_ID" value="#evaluate(temp)#">
                                        <cfinvokeargument name="StartDay" value="#dateFormat(form.cal,'dd')#">
                                        <cfinvokeargument name="StartMonth" value="#dateFormat(form.cal,'mm')#">
                                        <cfinvokeargument name="StartYear" value="#dateformat(form.cal,'yyyy')#">             
                                    </cfinvoke>
```

Comment: What is the scope of the variable? Use the same bracket notation syntax, just add the scope, ie `#scopeName["get_Advisors"& loopIndex]["advisor_ID"][someRowNumber]#`. Might also want to investigate whether the dynamic variable name is even necessary.

Comment: Currently "temp" is a variable scope, but if I can use direct notation I don't need a temporary variable.  I just knew I could get there by using an evaluate() on a temp dynamic... which works but is slow and not best practice.  

But the value I need is a cfquery "getAdvisor_Advisor.advisor_ID" is a cfquery with the advisor_ID column.

Comment: Try it with the bracket notation above. Though again, depending on what the code is doing, could be the dynamic name is not even needed.

Comment: I tried with the bracket notation it did not work.  Not sure if it was my syntax or what.

Comment: Worked fine in a quick test, so it is probably your syntax. Though, again ... I would recommend exploring whether you even need dynamic query names.

Comment: Does get_All_Appointments get appointments from another db table? Which dbms?

Comment: MS SQL, they are all in the same table.

Comment: Any reason you must use separate queries? Querying within a loop is very inefficient. This sounds like a perfect job for a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question, you can use QueryToStruct. Set an array with each index being a structure of the query.

```
<!--- CREATE THE ARRAY --->
<cfset temp = arrayNew(1)>

<cfquery name="getAdvisor_Advisors1" dbtype="query" cachedWithin="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,15,0)#">
    Select *
    rom getAdvisors
    Where Express = 'FR/SO' 
    Order by Specialization, Advisor
</cfquery>

<!--- CREATE AND FILL THE STRUCT --->
<cfset temp[1] = QueryToStruct(getAdvisor_Advisors1)>
```

Then later you can loop over that array `temp` and output the values.

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(temp)#" index="t">
    ...
    <cfinvokeargument name="Advisor_ID" value="#temp[t].advisor_ID#">
    ...
</cfloop>
```

Info for QueryToStruct: https://gist.github.com/erikvold/764276

Here is a screenshot of it working: [image]

**Original answer:**
Why not use the query for the `cfloop`, or `cfoutput`? Then it's trivial:

```
<cfloop query = "getAdvisor_Advisor">
<cfinvoke component="com.appointments" method="get_All_Appointments" returnvariable="getAppointments">
      <cfinvokeargument name="Advisor_ID" value="#getAdvisor_Advisors.advisor_ID#">
      <cfinvokeargument name="StartDay" value="#dateFormat(form.cal,'dd')#">
      <cfinvokeargument name="StartMonth" value="#dateFormat(form.cal,'mm')#">
      <cfinvokeargument name="StartYear" value="#dateformat(form.cal,'yyyy')#">             
</cfinvoke>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: This will not work because I"m not looking for the current row of the getAdvisor_Advisor query I'm looking for the current row of getAdvisor_Advisor#X# query.  Which is one of 4 different query of queries, depending upon where we are in the index loop.

Comment: Oh I see. I'll rewrite my answer when I get back to my desktop.

Comment: This Looks right, your revised answer however when I try that the page dies as soon as it hits <cfset temp[1] = QueryToStruct(getAdvisor_Advisors1)>  Like it cannot run that part... also there is no error message.

Comment: You first have to create the array with `arrayNew(1)`. If you use a regular 2 dimensional array, you can put a struct in it. I amended my answer.

Comment: Did you download and insert the function from the link I posted?

Comment: Where do I insert the function?

Comment: Anywhere in the template.

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach is more complicated than necessary and you have too much going on inside your loop.  Start with the things that don't change with each loop iteration.

```
myObject = CreateObject("component","com.appointments");
argumentStructure = StructNew();
argumentStructure.StartDay= dateFormat(form.cal,'dd');
argumentStructure.StartMonth= dateFormat(form.cal,'mm');
argumentStructure.StartYear = dateFormat(form.cal,'yyyy');
</cfscript>
```

Then do your loop.

```
<cfloop query = "getAdvisor_Advisor">
<cfscript>
argumentStructure.advisor_ID = advisor_ID;
variableFromObject = myObject.get_All_Appointments(argumentCollection = argumentStructure);
//  code to process that variable
</cfscript>
</cfloop>
```

Note that the question has no information about what the method is returning.  That particular detail could affect the last part of the answer.

Comment: This returns all of the appointments for a given date on the calendar and a given advisor.  It is then inside of a loop that is looping over groups of advisors.

Answer (score 1):

```
variables["getAdvisor_Advisors#LoopCount#"].advisor_ID[variables["getAdvisor_Advisors#LoopCount#"].currentRow]`
```

also remember that variables usually reference objects so you can also clean up code by referencing it by another variable name...

```
currentQuery = variables["getAdvisor_Advisors#LoopCount#"];
currentQuery.advisor_ID[currentQuery.currentRow]`
```

---

Also an additional suggestion. When I want to have a list of queries or actions to be taken I will usually either put the queries into a struct and then iterate over them or have a list of names to loop over.

So for example if the order doesn't matter...

```
<cfset queries = {} />
<cfquery name="queries.AdvisoryQuery1Name" ...>
    ...
</query>
<cfloop collection="#queries#" ...
```

or if the order does matter and there is a known set of names you can loop over a list or array. The list could also be dynamically generated.

```
<cfloop list="FR_SO_ExpressAdvisors,JR_SR_ExpressAdvisors,etc" index="queryname">
    <cfset query = variables[queryname] />
    .... etc
```

Both of these allow you to name the queries in a more descriptive way.